# Retrofit2 bad format response

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have tried some different things already with no success so I was thinking of changing to some other library and try, but I will leave this here first just in case.

I have an app that makes 2 GET and 2 POST to 3 different URLs, and I'm having trouble with the last one.

I have this Retrofit POST method:

```
@Headers({
            "Accept: text/html",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    })
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("index.php?operacion=consulta")
    Call<String> postRaiaSearch(@Header("Cookie") String cookie, @Field("microchip") String microchip);
```

And, before I explain the problem I want to clarify that I already tried changin `Call<String>` with `Call<ResponseBody>`, or sending the payload as `@Field` (with `@FormUrlEncoded` and the `Content-Type` header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) and also like a `@Body` with `RequestBody`.

But everything gives to me the same wrong formatted response.

Here is a sample of the Advanced REST Client response body nicely formatted:

RAW:
[image]

PARSED:
[image]

And the monster that Retrofit is giving to me:

[image]

As you can see, the first bad thing is that the web returns an HTML instead of a JSON, but I thought I could just obtain it as raw plain text, but that did not go well.

In case you wonder, this is how I made the Retrofit object:

```
public static Retrofit getRaiaApi() {
    if (raiaRetrofit == null) {
        raiaRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RAIA_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return raiaRetrofit;
}
```

And I also tried adding `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`, or deleting the Scalars line (with the Gson one only), or even just deleting both of them.

I don't think you really need the method that's calling that POST method, but I will paste it anyway:

```
private void nextRaiaSearch(String header) {
    callRaiaSearch = apiInterfaceRaia.postRaiaSearch(header, chipInput);
    callRaiaSearch.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            Log.v("call", "onResponse");
            Log.v("call", response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("call", "onFailure");
        }
    });
}
```

Should I try something like Volley or any other thing instead of Retrofit just for this one request?

The imports made are:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
```

Comment: which type of api you are using  ( send data to server or receive data fro server )  GET or POST

Comment: It's a POST and I want the response, so receive, but the main problem is that the web doesn't have an API, so it gives to you the whole HTML of the web, and I would gladly take it, I can extract the values I want from there, but you can see the format that Android is giving to me, full of diamonds and interrogations

Comment: Can I ask why are you setting the content type of the request to ``Content-Type: text/plain`` and adding the Gson converter? shouldn't it be ``Content-Type: application/json`` which is what retrofit puts by default.

Comment: I have tried with `text/plain`, `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` already, with different converters for each solution,

Comment: in post few method is used to send the data  <key ,value> , jsonbody , form-data which one you are using . or check which format accepted in api please check and rply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got a solution for that response mess I was recieving. The problem was one of the headers of the POST method:

`Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`

A header I was told to put but I didn't need at all, since it was compressing the text. Now I get normal response answers, just like in the raw Advanced REST Client response:

[image]